# Split numeric from character data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

It's possible to split this data?

```
DATA
----------
FORD3000
MILLER1300
```

I want to make it like this:

```
ENAME | SAL
------------
FORD    3000
MILLER  1300
```

Comment: Are there any records for which your desired `ENAME` contains a digit, or your desired `SAL` contains anything other than a digit?

Comment: Digits are characters too :) But if you mean what I think you mean, then podiluska's approach should be correct.

Comment: @hvd well you understood )). Yes podiluska good responded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

```
 select 
    substring(data, 1, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',data)-1) as ename,
    substring(data, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',data), len(data)) as sal
 from 
     table
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(@ourName, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', @ourName)) AS [First],
SUBSTRING(@ourName, CHARINDEX(' ', @ourName) + 2, LEN(@ourName)) AS[Last]
```